# What do all these log messages mean?

Tags: log

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS kernel version 5.16.3-051603-generic. I'm getting these log messages in the logs application. What do these messages mean? Do I need to worry? Will they cause some big problem?

```
[drm:dc_link_detect_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* No EDID read.
Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online.
GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Device: /dev/sda [SAT], ATA error count increased from 13138 to 13142
kfd kfd: amdgpu: device 1002:15d8 NOT added due to errors
[drm:dc_link_detect_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* No EDID read.
Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 105, async page read
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
I/O error, dev sda, sector 249133056 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 105, async page read
I/O error, dev sda, sector 2888 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
I/O error, dev sda, sector 1287680 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210930/psparse-529)
```

Here is the screenshot of the log messages for clarity :
[image: screenshot]

If you want to see those message wrapped inside the main message, you can tell me.

Thanks

---

## UPDATE

Screenshot of **SMART Data & self-Tests** window from disks application. (I had run a self test yesterday):
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]

---

UPDATE (After the solution)
I'm getting this at the very start.
What do they mean? [image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134122/discussion-between-mudit-and-heynnema).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134132/discussion-on-question-by-mudit-what-do-all-these-log-messages-mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SSD firmware**

For ADATA SU650 (V8X04c12), see https://www.adata.com/en/download/503?tab=downloads. Or see https://www.adata.com/pk/support/consumer?tab=downloads&download=software. There's a Nov 2021 update available.

**Note**: Backup your important data BEFORE doing a firmware update.

**NCQ errors**

`grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs/etc., and watch `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

<strike>**Bad Block**</strike>

**The `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda7 > badsectors.txt` command should NOT be used.** Especially on a SSD.

If you read `man badblocks` you'll see *"...it  is  strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs..."*.

Here is the **correct** way to do bad blocking on **HDDs**...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

**Note: do NOT bad block a SSD**

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

**Note: you may have a pending HDD failure**

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```