# Cannot Boot Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

My Ubuntu 20.04 kernel version 5.16.3-051603-generic stuck in emergency mode. It is installed in a SSD with Windows 10 on it too. The problem arise after installing a new 500 GB  hard drive (Nothing Ubuntu related files installed on this disk). I had same problem like this where I was not able to boot[This problem with NCQ errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392700/what-do-all-these-log-messages-mean/1392888#1392888). A folk from the community helped me by adding a `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"` command in the grub menu and said to update the SSD firmware (No firmware update available for my SSD yet).

Here is the screenshots message I get now when I boot:
[image]

After the loading screen, I get this:
[image]
It looks like there is problem with windows partitions and Ubuntu partitions. I don't know exactly.

System Information:

1. 2 disk are present, 1 is Adata's 240gb SSD and 1 is Seagate 500gb HDD.
2. Ubuntu and windows both OS are installed in the SSD and the HDD are totally empty now.

I guess the SSD does not have any blocks on it because when I checked it in windows no blocks are found. But in Ubuntu it says logical blocks. It is weird.
If anyone can help, It would be very helpful.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

The problem has been solved. I wanted to increase the Ubuntu partitions space, so I did it.

- First, I Boot with the live USB.
- Resize the partition (root, home) with gparted.
- And Try to boot again and it worked.

I am still getting buffer error message in the start, but Ubuntu is booting fine. I did check the SSD with smart tools and think I should ask a different question for that.

Comment: Hello. The fuzzy pictures can not be hardly read. They appear to be hard drive errors from the bit I can see. That would imply that the hard drive is dead or will be soon.

Comment: What OS are you using? as your kernel used is not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS supported kernel.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I updated the kernel because of black screen on boot error. Kernel 5.13.xx always have that problem.

Comment: But the windows access the hard drive easily and ubuntu is only installed in SSD not hard drive. Does Ubuntu also try to access the HDD? @David

Comment: All I can say is the pictures are almost impossible to read.

Comment: Both windows & Ubuntu could share a drive that contains problems, but one is flawless as it exists on the part of the disk that still works; where as the other may exist/use areas that are problematic/dying.. We can't know what devices you have setup for use for each OS; we're limited to details you provide - which as per @David's comment, the messages show clear problems with device sda  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Sorry for the bad Images. If there is some problem with sda drive(which is SSD). How can I know what is the exact problem and what is the solution for it?

Comment: Use the drive's inbuilt SMART tools ; refer my prior link.  Almost any drive made in the last 15+ years (*good drives before then too!*) keeps logs and the SMART - Self Monitoring Analysis & Reporting Technology... lets you read the drive condition, and see if the drive needs replacing.

Comment: Disconnect the HDD and see if your Ubuntu boots like it supposed to. If that is the case the HDD causes the problem. If you have an external case lying around ( usb to sata/ide ) try that.